# How to rotate Java logging files backwards?

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public class LogerrDemoRotating {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("myapplog%g.log", 1024, 10, true);
        handler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());

        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        logger.addHandler(handler);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "AAAAAAAAAA " + i);
        }
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LogerrDemoRotating.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

I am using `%g` to rotate files.

When this application is run 9 files of log (`myapplog0.log` through `myapplog8.log`) and a `.lck` file will be created.

My problem is that `myapplog0.log` contains latest logs and `myapplog8.log` contains oldest log.

Can this be reversed? I want to `myapplog0.log` contains oldest logs and `myapplog8.log` contains newest log.

Comment: Which `Logger` is that?

Comment: I get your problem, but may I suggest using timestamp instead of log0, log1... It will make you use less code, solve your problem and help you located quicker what you are looking for.